# How to merge two column in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnusedTicketAmount" HeaderText="UnusedTicketAmount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlUnusedAmount" HeaderText="ddlUnusedAmount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AirlinePenality" HeaderText="AirlinePenality" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlAirlinePenality" HeaderText="ddlAirlinePenality" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NetRefundProcess" HeaderText="NetRefundProcess" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlNetRefundProcess" HeaderText="ddlNetRefundProcess" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundableCommission" HeaderText="RefundableCommission" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlRefundableCommission" HeaderText="ddlRefundableCommission" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CouponRefunded" HeaderText="CouponRefunded" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundType" HeaderText="RefundType" />
```

in this gridview i want to add airlinepenality and ddlairlinepanelity to one column
how can i do that thanks in advance

Comment: what type is that fields int or Varchar...?

Comment: airlinepenality is textbox with nvarchar datatype and ddlairlinepenality is dropdown list with float datatype

Comment: Both have money value right...?

Comment: sry airline penality is float value sry

Comment: What Data Source you are using to bind this GridView...?

Comment: The question is misleading. The question states clearly how to merge TWO columns, not how to merge two fields into ONE column. Merging two columns like in a table row where you merge two columns to make once cell across two columns is what the question implies. Downvoted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a template field and bind two fields like this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Airlinepenality"   SortExpression="ddlAirlinePenality">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AirlinePenality")+ " " + Eval("ddlAirlinePenality")%>' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `Bound field`, `we can merge two columns by TemplateField` only, So better `you can merge that two columns in your query`,

try like below...

**Query:**

```
SELECT UnusedTicketAmount, ddlUnusedAmount, 
cast(1.25 as varchar) + ' ' + cast(172813.99 as varchar) as AirlinePenality,
NetRefundProcess,ddlNetRefundProcess,RefundableCommission
ddlRefundableCommission,CouponRefunded,RefundType
```

**Gridview**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="UnusedTicketAmount" HeaderText="UnusedTicketAmount" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ddlUnusedAmount" HeaderText="ddlUnusedAmount" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="AirlinePenality" HeaderText="AirlinePenality" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="NetRefundProcess" HeaderText="NetRefundProcess" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ddlNetRefundProcess" HeaderText="ddlNetRefundProcess" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="RefundableCommission" HeaderText="RefundableCommission" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ddlRefundableCommission" HeaderText="ddlRefundableCommission" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CouponRefunded" HeaderText="CouponRefunded" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="RefundType" HeaderText="RefundType" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to merge last three columns of your grid then you can also use the below code:

```
  protected void grdAirTicketList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
      {
          e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
          e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
          e.Row.Cells[6].Attributes.Add("colspan", "3");
      }
  }
```

This means your column named 'CouponRefunded' and 'RefundType' will not be visible and 'ddlRefundableCommission' will be visible with colspan 3.